# Создание простой нейросети

Tags: c#, vb.net, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Доброго времени суток. Допустим хочу сделать простую нейросеть для XOR:

---

**X=0, У=0, О=0 | X=1, У=0, О=1 | Х=0, У=1, О=1 | Х=1, У=1, О=0**

---

Я так понимаю, что 1,1 и 2,1 входные и им передается значение без изменения. После передачи сигналы далее, в каждом нейроне значение умножается на вес и т.д. В конце я должен сравнить выходы 1,3 и 2,3 и получить ответ, если это 1 ряд, то ответ 0, если 2 ответ 1.
[image: пример нейросети]
Для простоты пусть класс нейрон содержит вес на каждый вход (т.е. 2) и силу сигнала:

```
Class Neuron
    Public weight() As Double = {0, 0}
    Public power As Double = 0.0
End Class
```

Дальше создаем массив и получаем случайный вес, в пределах единицы:

```
Dim neural(2, 1) As Neuron
Dim rand As New Random
For I As Integer = 0 To 2 Step 1
    For J As Integer = 0 To 1 Step 1
        neural(I, J) = New Neuron
        neural(I, J).weight(0) = rand.NextDouble()
        neural(I, J).weight(1) = rand.NextDouble()
    Next
Next
```

Получаем входные значения:

```
neural(0, 0).power = Console.ReadLine()
neural(0, 1).power = Console.ReadLine()
```

Функция активации:

```
Function Sigmoid(ByRef int As Double) As Double
    Const e_sigmoid As Double = 2.71828
    Return (1 / (1 + (e_sigmoid ^ (-(int)))))
End Function
```

И простой код работы этой нейронной сети:

```
For I As Integer = 1 To 2 Step 1
    neural(I, 0).power = Sigmoid(((neural(I - 1, 0).power * neural(I, 0).weight(0)) + (neural(I - 1, 1).power * neural(I, 0).weight(1))))
    neural(I, 1).power = Sigmoid(((neural(I - 1, 0).power * neural(I, 1).weight(0)) + (neural(I - 1, 1).power * neural(I, 1).weight(1))))
Next
```

Вот у меня вопрос будет ли это работать и как её обучить? Примеры не важно на чем.

Comment: Есть готовые инструменты. Вы с целью обучения?
Да, так же можно через IronPython юзать библиотеки Python'а

Comment: Теперь вам надо backpropagation сделать для вашей сети. Без этого не получится её обучить. Для такой простой сети можно градиентный спуск реализовать. Это обычно медленнее, но проще в реализации.

Comment: И для XOR должно хватить трех нейронов

Comment: Я обучить ее не могу, потому что не могу понять как рассчитать погрешность: погрешность равна разнице между ожидаемым результатом и результатом нейрона. Так вот, выход у нейрона допустим какой нибудь 0.7, а рассматриваем 1 XOR 1 = 0, значит 0 - 0.7?

Comment: Просто если возможно, можно ли привести пример на коленке, псевдокод и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прислушался к комментарию о 3-х нейронах. Простая реализация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Module Module1

    'Переменные НС:
    Dim enters() As Double = {0, 0}
    Dim hidden_layer() As Double = {0, 0}
    Dim output As Double = 0
    Dim synapses_hidden(,) As Double = {{0.0, 0.1}, {0.0, 0.1}}
    Dim synapses_out() As Double = {0.1, 0.0}

    'Данные для обучения:
    Dim learn(,) As Integer = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}
    'Обучает всем ответам кроме 0 - 0 - 1:
    Dim learn_answer() As Integer = {0, 1, 1, 1}

    Sub Main()
        'Обучаем НС:
        Console.WriteLine("::: TRAINING NETWORK START :::")
        'Глобальная переменная и временная:
        Dim global_error As Double = 0.0
        Dim currect_error As Double = 0.0
        'Массив ошибок:
        Dim errors(hidden_layer.Length - 1)
        'Счетчик итераций:
        Dim iteration As Integer = 0

        'Выполняем пока есть ошибка:
        Do
            global_error = 0
            For I As Integer = 0 To learn.Length / 2 - 1 Step 1
                'Заполняем вход для НС:
                enters(0) = learn(I, 0)
                enters(1) = learn(I, 1)

                'Суммируем:
                StartNetwork()

                'Получаем погрешность:
                currect_error = learn_answer(I) - output
                'Пишем в глобальную:
                global_error += Math.Abs(currect_error)
                'Пишем в массив ошибок:
                For J As Integer = 0 To errors.Length - 1 Step 1
                    errors(J) = currect_error * synapses_out(J)
                Next
                'Корректируем веса (от выхода к входу):
                For J As Integer = 0 To enters.Length - 1 Step 1
                    For K As Integer = 0 To synapses_hidden.Length / 2 - 1 Step 1
                        synapses_hidden(K, J) += 0.1 * errors(J) * enters(J)
                    Next
                Next
                'Меняем следующий слой:
                For J As Integer = 0 To synapses_out.Length - 1 Step 1
                    synapses_out(J) += 0.1 * currect_error * hidden_layer(J)
                Next
            Next
            iteration += 1
        Loop While global_error <> 0
        Console.WriteLine("::: NUMBER OF ITERATIONS OF THE TRAINING -> " + iteration.ToString + " TIMES :::")

        'Запуск НС
        For I As Integer = 0 To learn.Length / 2 - 1 Step 1
            'Заполняем входные данные
            enters(0) = learn(I, 0)
            enters(1) = learn(I, 1)
            'Суммируем
            StartNetwork()
            'Выводим результат
            Console.WriteLine(output)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub StartNetwork()
        'Суммируем для скрытого слоя:
        For I As Integer = 0 To hidden_layer.Length - 1 Step 1
            hidden_layer(I) = 0
            For J As Integer = 0 To enters.Length - 1 Step 1
                hidden_layer(I) += synapses_hidden(I, J) * enters(J)
            Next
            'Функция активации:
            If hidden_layer(I) > 0.5 Then
                hidden_layer(I) = 1.0
            Else
                hidden_layer(I) = 0.0
            End If
        Next
        output = 0
        'Выходной слой:
        For I As Integer = 0 To hidden_layer.Length - 1 Step 1
            output += synapses_out(I) * hidden_layer(I)
        Next
        'Функция активации:
        If output > 0.5 Then
            output = 1
        Else
            output = 0
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```